Extracting path and filename from a string containing both in vanilla SQLITE
I have a SQLITE DB that contains fullnames (i.e., parentpath\filename, e.g.
C:\Users\Public\My Music\Classic Queen\16 - Who Wants to Live Forever.mp3
I want to query and get the filename separate from the parentpath.
In other SQL instances I'd use reverse to find the last backslash, but SQLITE does not support it. Previous answers focused on doing in an external script (python). My question is how to query Sqlite directly.
P.S.,
I'm working with the AllDup database, but this question is not unique to it.

This can be achieved in sqlite with some "creative" use of the right-trim and string replacement functions.
# Table 'files' contain the fullname in the 'file' column
# .mode is set to line for readability

sqlite> SELECT
  file AS fullname,
  RTRIM(file, REPLACE(file, '\', '')) AS parentpath,
  REPLACE(file, 
    RTRIM(file, REPLACE(file, '\', '')),
    '') AS filename
FROM files

  fullname = C:\Users\Public\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music\Nirvana\Last Concert In Japan\16 Smells Like Teen Spirit.mp3
parentpath = C:\Users\Public\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music\Nirvana\Last Concert In Japan\
  filename = 16 Smells Like Teen Spirit.mp3

Why this works? We typically think of rtrim as a function that removes spaces or a specified trim string from the end of the source string. Thus rtrim('abc','c') = ab.
However, it actually is working on a match of any and all characters in any order at the end of both source and trim strings. Thus rtrim('abc','dec') = ab and rtrim('abc','cb') = a.
Knowing that, we first replace the path separators in the file string and rtrim it against the original string. Since only the filename portion matches, it is removed -- giving us the parent path we seek.
We then we then replace the parent path from the original string -- resulting in the filename we seek.
